# Delete row based on fill color index

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete all rows with in the range of `A7:AI300` that contain a cell with yellow fill (Color index 6)  I have some code that will delete all rows that contain the color but the problem I am having is that it is trying to run the code for the whole worksheet and will freeze my workbook.  I am trying to insert a range to speed up the calculations. Can anyone show me how to insert the range so it works

```
Sub deleterow()
   Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In Selection
       If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
           cell.EntireRow.Delete
       End If
   Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have data till column AI300?

Comment: `Find` has an option to SearchFormats. No loop needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? Notice that we are not deleting each row inside the loop but creating our final "Delete Range" This will ensure that your code runs faster.

**EDIT**: If you are looking at range `"A7:A300"` then use this code

```
Sub deleterow()
   Dim cell As Range, DelRange As Range

   For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:A300")
       If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
           If DelRange Is Nothing Then
               Set DelRange = cell
           Else
               Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, cell)
           End If
       End If
   Next cell

   If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

And if you are looking at range `"A7:AI300"` then I guess this is what you want.

```
Sub deleterow()
   Dim cell As Range, DelRange As Range

   For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:AI300")
       If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
           If DelRange Is Nothing Then
               Set DelRange = cell
           Else
               Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, cell)
           End If
       End If
   Next cell

   If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
End Sub
```

**MORE FOLLOWUP**

I think I might have finally understood what you are trying to achieve...

```
Sub deleterow()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim delRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 7 To 300 '<~~ Row 7 to 300
            For j = 1 To 35 <~~ Col A to AI
                If .Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                    If delRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set delRange = .Cells(i, j)
                    Else
                        Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(i, j))
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I keep getting a 1004 error on line "If cell.Interior.ColorIndex =6 Then"  how would you fix that?

Comment: Which line? I have tested the code and it works just fine... Did you chnage the name of the sheet in the above code?

Comment: line five and yes i did change the sheet

Comment: oops a typo... did you mean `A7:AI300` or `A7:A300`

Comment: Gr8! My sincere apologies for taking so much time to understand your query! It's one of those days I guess...

Comment: No worries It is amazing I have someone to help me, I do have one more question though... If i wanted to add another fill color to delete from the worksheet how would i insert the index number

Comment: If `.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Or .Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = <Whatever Number> Then`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do. Put calculations on manual mode. Set the range you need to delete, instead of `selecting`...

```
Sub deleterow()
     Dim myRange as Range
     Dim cell As Range

     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A300") '-- just column A would do

     For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
          cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
     Next cell

     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Sub
```

Comment: @David, one cell in `column A` refers to the entire row. So if once cell is yellow, can delete that entire row. You don't have go through each cell in the whole sheet. Happy to hear comments after trying out :)

Comment: I get a 1004 error on the row where you set the range (line 4)

Comment: @DavidVanderVieren Please set it the sheet that you need, whether it is sheet 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: @DavidVanderVieren you need to put the code snippet in a `module`. It works really fine in my end, that's why I posted :)

Comment: it is still giving me a 1004 error it says "unable to get the Interior property of the Range class"

Comment: @DavidVanderVieren I wish I could show you the sheet. It works perfectly fine in my end. Is your sheet protected? Anyway it seems you have gotten the answer from Sidharth. And you did get the same error in his code too. So please do any changes you have done :)