# Need suggestions on how to speed up this bit of code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that can import a bunch of data from 3 different types of files. It formats it so that the output will be the same for all three, in one case it needs to delete rows based on what is in the cells of that row.  The problem is that this takes about 1.5 to 2 minutes to do compared to seconds it takes for the formatting of the other files (the ones without rung deletes).  The worksheet starts out around 4000 rows and deletes about 1600 of them.  My current way of doing it works fine and everything works but is there a way of doing this that would run faster?

```
rw = 1
Lastrow = 2600
NewRow = 0

NxtChk2:
    If (Worksheets("ARCSRT.CND").Cells(rw, "c") >= "0") And (Worksheets("ARCSRT.CND").Cells(rw, "d") = "") Then
        Worksheets("ARCSRT.CND").Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
        rw = rw - 1
    End If
    If (Worksheets("ARCSRT.CND").Cells(rw, "b") = "0.0") And (Worksheets("ARCSRT.CND").Cells(rw, "c") = "") Then
        Worksheets("ARCSRT.CND").Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
        rw = rw - 1
    End If
    If rw = Lastrow Then GoTo LATER
    rw = rw + 1
GoTo NxtChk2
```

Comment: First, turn off screenupdating, set calculation to manual, and disable events.  If that does not speed it up enough, try doing all the work in VBA using arrays and collections, so as to avoid the multiple read/write to the worksheet. See Chip Pearson's website for how to read and write an array to a range in a single step.

Comment: Everything is already turned off, that is why the other two file types run fast enough.  I haven't tried arrays and will check out Chips site.  Thanks.

Comment: David, I fail to see how your link or the answer below has anything to do with my question.  I am asking how to speed up the deletion of rungs in Excel, not replacement of words in Word.  I'm at a loss to figure out what you two are talking about unless there is something I'm missing.

Comment: In particular pay attension to [Sids method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13977536/445425) : collect all rows to be deleted into a range, them delete them in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following from my comment, try the following
this to go before the loop:
`Dim rng As Range`

`Set rng = Nothing`

in the loop instead of row delete do this:

`If rng = Nothing Then`
    `rng = Cells(rw, "A")`
`Else`
    `rng = Union(rng, Cells(rw, "A"))`
`End If`

and then after the loop has finished:

`rng.EntireRow.Delete`

bear in mind i am not sure how will it run on 1600 non-consecutive rows, run on a backup copy

Comment: I ended up using a variation on your answer and the answer provided by Chris Neilsen.  You were correct in that marking the line and then adding that to a range, then deleting the entire range in one go is faster.  I know mark my line based on my existing criteria and then use the code from Siddharth Rout's answer to set and delete the range.  My cycle time for the macro to run has gone down to about 1 minute.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting of the list is an option, instead of deleting row one by one just mark them with a "flag", i.e. letter "X" in a separate column, once the cycle finished, get your code to sort data on that column and just delete the whole batch of flagged rows in one go, it will do the deletion operation once and not 1600 times.

Comment: Very interesting, I still have to use code line by line to determine if the line needs to be deleted and marking it.  Is that faster than just deleting the row outright? (Is putting an X in a cell faster to process than deleting a row?)  I can't sort my data without putting it back in the same order after deleting the rows as I need to maintain the format of the other two files.  My other thought is how would I delete 1600 non-adjacent rows in one go?  I appreciate the input!

Comment: miles faster. It is similar to the comparison between deleting hundreds of lines filter out on some criteria which is non-consecutive compare to deleting same line but sorting on the filtered criteria first.
P.S. i tried to play around with trying to build a union of all rows needing deletion, but it won't hold that many lines to delete, rough count, it would to a 100 tops.
P.P.S how about doing the cycle in reverse: deleting rows from bottom up is quicker too?

Comment: actually try the following, `dim rng as Range`, `set rng = nothing`, then instead of row deletion try the following:
`If rng = Nothing Then  
    rng = Cells(rw, "A")  
Else  
    rng = Union(rng, Cells(rw, "A"))  
End If  
`

and then after the whole loop ran do this: `rng.EntireRow.Delete
`
please note i am not sure how it will work on 1600 non-consecutive ranges so do on a backup file

P.S. hmmm, i really should figure out how to do comments in a nicer way with line breaks, will post the code in a separate answer in a sec