# Removing data from one sheet that appears in another using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets with a table on each. One with original data (2000+ rows) and one with data I want to remove from the original data (500 or so rows). I have the following code to do this, however it is rather slow and I am sure it could be faster:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet, wsDelete As Worksheet
Dim str As String
Dim i as Long
Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")
Set wsDelete = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PermaDelete")

For i = wsDelete.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    str = wsDelete.Cells(i, 1).Value & wsDelete.Cells(i, 2).Value & wsDelete.Cells(i, 3).Value & wsDelete.Cells(i, 4).Value & wsDelete.Cells(i, 5).Value
    Set r = wsOriginal.Columns(30).Find(str, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext) ' Column 30 on original has concatenation of the required 5 rows, to match form of str
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Do
            wsOriginal.Rows(r.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            Set r = wsOriginal.Columns(30).Find(str, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
        Loop Until r Is Nothing
    End If
Next i
```

So I loop through each row in `wsDelete` and use `.Find` to find a row in the larger `wsOriginal`. If it finds it, then delete it and look for the same row again (as a few do duplicate this info across more than 1 line). To me that sounds like the quicker way of doing it (rather than loop through `wsOriginal`) but the code itself seems to take rather a long time (2-3 minutes). I am using the usual tricks of `.ScreenUpdating` and `.EnableEvents` set to false as well.

How else can I optimise this to cut down on wait times?

Comment: If the sheet wsOriginal has formulas then it is recalculating them after each delete event. Do __Application.Calculation = xlManual__ to stop the recalculations.

Comment: Ah yes. Hadn't thought of that. Could well shave off a fair bit of time. Will try it in a bit and report back.

Comment: Yeah switching to manual calculation dropped it to under a minute. Will try and somehow adapt the `Union` idea mentioned below and see if I can get that working for a bit of an extra boost.

Answer (score 0):

i replied to a similar post recently here: [Need suggestions on how to speed up this bit of code [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293749/need-suggestions-on-how-to-speed-up-this-bit-of-code)

this to go before the loop:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Nothing
```

in the loop instead of row delete do this:

```
If rng is Nothing Then
  rng =  wsOriginal.Cells(r.Row, 1)
Else
  rng = Union(rng,  wsOriginal.Cells(r.Row, 1))
End If
```

and then after the loop has finished:

```
rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

**EDIT**
fixed the typo above, apologies, to have a get around the `.Find` bit:
after you do `set r` add a line: `firstAddress = r.Address` and change `Loop Until` to `Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress`
this is quite nicely explained here: [Range.Find Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Not a bad answer, but this does not work too well with duplicates, as the `.Find` method will always return that row and therefore the line `Loop Until r Is Nothing` will never complete. Also, the code should read `If rng Is Nothing` not `If rng = Nothing`

Comment: Have tweaked it to now use `.FindNext` (which I have found a bit more hit and miss) and now have it working using this method (while also having it store the original address. However the time difference now is negligable compared to the original code (2 seconds off the time - 55 seconds to 53 seconds based on 2 runs) so will revert back to the original version. Think it is the duplicate checking that means it is not as effective than if you were using a list with no duplicates.

Comment: strange that the speed difference is not noticeable - deleting complex range in one go is usually much faster than deleting one line at a time.. P.S. i have edited my original post for the `.Find` get around.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but think the main bulk of the time is probably being taken up with the `.Find` method itself rather than the deleting of rows (especially if `.Calculation` is turned off, which it is now). Because, in essence, I am looping through 2000 rows at least 500-600 times (minimum twice for each row in `wsDelete`) then I dont think the deleting will be doing much in terms of making a dint into the overall time. If it were purely deleting, then it would probably be a more noticeable percentage and therefore more worthwhile.

Answer (score -1):

There is a pretty simple workaround to this. Excel's REMOVE DUPLICATE logic is to remove the duplicate that appears lower in the spreadsheet.

If you would like to remove all the items from sheet 2 that appear in sheet 1, simply paste the items from sheet 2 at the top of sheet 1, run the REMOVE DUPLICATE functions for the column, and then delete all the items from sheet 2.

Easy as that.

Comment: Solution in code was required hence asking for code optimization rather than alternatives.